# Trouble configuring FORM authentication for Spring Boot/Security App using Pre-Authentication

Tags: spring-security, tomcat7, spring-boot

I have successfully configured a spring boot application to use spring security pre-authentication framework, relying on Tomcat 7 container to authenticate from the tomcat-users.xml file.  I was also able to add a custom AuthenticationUserDetailsService to map authorities to users authenticated by the container (I don't want to manage application roles in the container).  It took me awhile to get the Java configuration down but I got it all working like a charm....but ONLY when I use BASIC authentication (as configured in web.xml). When I try to convert to FORM authentication, things go wrong in the middle of the filter chain.

The login form, as configured in web.xml, is rendering (using themeleaf as in [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/3.2.x/samples/preauth-jc)).  I also see from the logs that the user is successfully authenticating which means that is communicating with the container as expected.  I also see the J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter picking up the J2EE principal and calling the custom AuthenticationUserDetailsService to map the roles.  However, a little bit further down in the logs it appears that the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository gets a null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT (while going through the filter chain for '/login'?). As a result, seems to have no reference to the J2EE principal anymore and subsequently creates a SecurityContextHolder with an 'anonymous token'.  It does this despite the fact that I see it find the '[permitAll]' that I have configured for the '/login' url (in Spring config).

Here is an excerpt from my web.xml:

```
    <!-- Define a Security Constraint on this Application -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secured (entire app)</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>USER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <!-- Define the Login Configuration for this Application -->
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login?error</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
    <security-role>
        <description>
            The role that is required to access the application
        </description>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

Accordingly, my tomcat-users.xml has a user with username of 'user' and a role of 'USER'. I don't precede with 'ROLE_' as I am not trying to map any roles into the app.  I use my custom AuthenticationUserDetailsService for this.

Here is my main config file.  Note, I also have a another class that implements the SpringBootServletInitializer and configures the SpringApplicationBuilder to point to this class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MyApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Controller
    protected static class HomeController {

        // ROLE_MYAPP_USER is mapped to all authenticated users by custom AuthenticationUserDetailsService
        @RequestMapping({"/", "/about", "/profile"})
        @Secured("ROLE_MYAPP_USER")
        public ModelAndView index(@CurrentUser User user) {
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
            model.put("currentUser", user);
            //noinspection SpringMVCViewInspection
            return new ModelAndView("index", model);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(VodConsoleApplication.class).run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new CurrentUserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationSecurity applicationSecurity() {
        return new ApplicationSecurity();
    }

    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable();

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/partials/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/vendor/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .jee()
                .authenticatedUserDetailsService(new InMemoryUserDetailsService());
        http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/");

        }
    }
}
```

There is also a login.html form that posts to /j_security_check.  Let me know if you need that although it is pretty straight forward and it appears (from the logs) that it is working.

Again, everything works PERFECTLY with BASIC authentication configured in web.xml.  Once I go to FORM, I get the dropping of the J2EE principal in the middle of the filter processing chain.

Ideas? Could it be that I need to configure my web.xml security constraints differently?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  It turns out that I also needed to add url patterns to all my 'public' resources into the web.xml.  Specifically, the javascript (in 'vendor' and 'js' directories), the css, img, etc.  Here is my updated web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Public resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/vendor/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/partials/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secured (entire app)</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<!-- Define the Login Configuration for this Application -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login?error</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
<security-role>
    <description>
        The role that is required to access the application
    </description>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
</security-role>
```